# Placing tags around a substring in html using python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

My html script saved as `BeautifulSoup` object looks as below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Sundar Pichai is the CEO of Google</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I want to search the word Google alone from soup.p and wrap a snap tag around it thereby getting an updated soup object.

I have tried using

```
new_span=soup.new_tag('span',attrs={'class':'annotate'}) 
for p in soup.find('p'):
    p.find(string="Google").wrap(new_span)
```

Using this the find value gives `None` and hence error.

I have tried using compile from regular expressions

```
for p in soup.find('p'):
    p.find(string=re.compile("Google")).wrap(new_span)
```

This find returns the entire text in `p` tag and `span` is wrapped around the entire paragraph.

The output I want looks like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample</title>
    </head>
   <body>
        <p>Sundar Pichai is the CEO of <span class="annotate"> Google</span></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you would have to get full text from `<p>` and edit as normal text - ie. using `text.replace("Google", "<span class="annotate"> Google</span>")` - and then put full text back to `<p>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` works with tags and text inside tag is only one big element for `BS`. You can get tag as text (using `str()`), use standard text function to replace text `Google` with `<span class="annotate">Google</span>` and later use `BS` to convert all text to new `<p>` which you can use with `replace_with()` to replace old `<p>` with new `<p>`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

html = '''<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Sundar Pichai is the CEO of Google</p>
    </body>
</html>'''

soup = BS(html, 'html.parser')
p = soup.find('p')

text = str(p).replace("Google", '<span class="annotate">Google</span>')

p.replace_with(BS(text, 'html.parser'))

print(soup)
```

---

**EDIT:** you can also work with `p.string`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

html = '''<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Sundar Pichai is the CEO of Google</p>
    </body>
</html>'''

soup = BS(html, 'html.parser')
p = soup.find('p')

print('before:', list(p.children))

text = p.string.replace("Google", '<span class="annotate">Google</span>')
p.string.replace_with(BS(text, 'html.parser'))

print(' after:', list(p.children))

print(soup)
```

---

In this version I added `print(list(p.children))` to show that original `<p>` has only one child

```
['Sundar Pichai is the CEO of Google']
```

but it has to create two children

```
['Sundar Pichai is the CEO of ', <span class="annotate">Google</span>]`.
```

To do the same with `wrap()` you would have to remove `Google` from first child (string) and `append()` tag `<a>` (`BS('Google', 'html.parser').wrap(new_span)`) as second child.

Problem would be if `Google` is in then middle of string because you would have to create three children

```
['string before Google', <span class="annotate">Google</span>, 'string after Google']
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. It helped

Comment: Now I wish to search for the sub-string 'Google' and wish to put span tag around it as above only if it is not already enclosed inside a span tag. Can anyone comment on how can this be done. Thanks

Comment: create new question on new page. You will have more space to describe it and new people will see it.

Comment: Your first solution seems fragile since if you replace a smaller word it may match to a non-text element. For example 'pan' would match all 'span' elements.
The second solution seems robust to this and should be preferred.